# error OpenCV incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) for fingerprint detection

Tags: python, opencv

Sir my project loads all fingerprint pictures in TIF format but this command

```
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
```

please see the below error

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\features2d\src\sift.dispatch.cpp:512: error: (-5:Bad argument) image is empty or has incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) in function 'cv::SIFT_Impl::detectAndCompute'

this is my full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
fingerprint_test = cv2.imread("D:/mfapython/muhammadisthebest.tif")
cv2.imshow("Original", cv2.resize(fingerprint_test, None, fx=1, fy=1))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
for file in [file for file in os.listdir("D:/mfapython/fingerprintdatabase")]:
    fingerprint_database_image = cv2.imread("D:/mfapython/fingerprintdatabase/*.bmp", 1 )
    sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
    sift = .detectAndCompute() 
    keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(fingerprint_test, None)
    keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(fingerprint_database_image, None)
```

please guide me

thank you in advance for your valuable help

regard's

Comment: Typo error  `sift = .detectAndCompute()`

Comment: `sift = .detectAndCompute()` should be `sift = sift .detectAndCompute()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to write a comment, but as far as I can see from your code, the main issue is that you are trying to read the image in its native format (i.e colour image).

You need to either read it as grayscale using the mode as 0 (Grayscale) or use "**cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)**" to convert it into grayscale. The "**(!=CV-8U)**" indicates that it requires a grayscale image to be processed on.

The tutorial for feature matching is [here for your reference.](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html)

Comment: image8bit = cv2.normalize(fingerprint_database_image, none, 0, 255, cv2.norm_minmax).astype('uint8')     ===========sir I use this code but  it also gives me an error   please give me the right code that resolves this error